# struggle to pass data from a controller to a route

Tags: laravel, controller

i try to pass data thought controller, but i'm struggling.

my plan is to create a project in the database, and redirect to image.store with the project_id

that what i did:

```
 /**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $project = Project::all();        
    $validated = $this->validator($request); 
    
    $project = new Project();
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->description = $request->description;
    $project->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('add.image')->with( ['$request->name' => $request->name] );
}
```

and here is my route:

```
Route::get('image/create/{$project->name}', [Controller::class, 'create_image'])->name('add.image');
```

Comment: There are a lot of bad things in your controller: first don't do `Project::all()` if you are not going to use it and then re assign the variable to `new Project()`, you are calling the DB and doing nothing with it ! Second, what is that `$this->validator($request)` ? You can do `$request->validate($rules)` or use a `Form Request`, DO NOT OFUSCATE code. And finally, follow the standard, use CRUD, rename your controller action from `create_image` to `store` or `create`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $project = Project::all();        
    $validated = $this->validator($request); 
    
    $project = new Project();
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->description = $request->description;
    $project->save();

    $id = $project->id;
    
    return redirect()->route('add.image, $id')->with( ['id' => $id] );
}
```

Inside Route file:

```
Route::get('image/create/{id}', [Controller::class, 'create_image'])->name('add.image');
```

Comment: Try to share the documentation, so it is no magic for anyone: [Named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)